# Memory issue with ctypes and multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, c, numpy, multiprocessing, ctypes

I have a python code which uses ctypes to do some heavy lifting. It also uses multiprocessing. After realising I'd made an engineering (rather than programming) mistake in some code, I updated the c sub function and I now get a

```
    WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x09AA1000
```

which only occurs with the new c code and when multiprocessing is enabled. The address at the end is different every time, and the code will run succesfully for varying lengths of time before throwing the error. Here is the old (working) c code:

```
    void rfnies(double *array_ext, int tot_num, double *array_out) {
    double *pr, *po, a[16384], ampl, mean;
    int index, j, cNr;
    pr = array_ext;
    po = array_out;

    j = -1;
    cNr = 1;
    for (index=0; index<tot_num; index++) {
        a[++j]=*pr++;
        while ( (j >= 2) && (fabs(a[j-1]-a[j-2]) <= fabs(a[j]-a[j-1])) ) {
            ampl=fabs( (a[j-1]-a[j-2])/2 );
            switch(j)
    {
                case 0: { break; }
                case 1: { break; }
                case 2: {
                    mean=(a[0]+a[1])/2;
                    a[0]=a[1];
                    a[1]=a[2];
                    j=1;
                    if (ampl > 0) {
                        *po++=ampl;
                        *po++=mean;
                        *po++=0.50;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    mean=(a[j-1]+a[j-2])/2;
                    a[j-2]=a[j];
                    j=j-2;
                    if (ampl > 0) {
                        *po++=ampl;
                        *po++=mean;
                        *po++=1.00;
                        cNr++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (index=0; index<j; index++) {
        ampl=fabs(a[index]-a[index+1])/2;
        mean=(a[index]+a[index+1])/2;
        if (ampl > 0){
            *po++=ampl;
            *po++=mean;
            *po++=0.50;
        }
    }
    return;
    }
```

And here is the new code which causes the access violation. I can't see what the problem is and it is driving me insane!

```
    void rf3(double *array_ext, int tot_num, double *array_out) {
    double *pr, *po, E[tot_num], ampl, mean, XX, YY;
    int index, j, cNr, nn;
    pr = array_ext;
    po = array_out; 
    j=0;
    nn = -1;
    while (j<=tot_num){
        nn++;
        E[nn] = *(pr+j);
        j++;
        while (nn >= 2){
            XX = fabs(E[nn] - E[nn - 1]);
            YY = fabs(E[nn - 1] - E[nn - 2]);
            if (XX<YY){break;}
            ampl=YY/2.0;
            mean=(E[nn - 1] + E[nn - 2])/2.0;
            *po++=ampl;
            *po++=mean;
            *po++=1.00;
            nn = nn - 2;
            E[nn] = E[nn + 2];
        }

    }

}
```

The fact that it will run for varying lengths of time suggests that something is being left in memory and one of the other processes is trying to read the same memory. I can't post a working example as I can't even reproduce it in the full code on some runs!

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Run the script in a debugger that's configured to also debug child processes. The debugger will get a first chance exception, so you can print a stack trace and inspect local variables.